# When starting client the code is asking for phone/bot token

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

While running my first code using Telethon library, it is asking for a bot token.

This is the actual code:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events, sync
api_id = 1234567
api_hash = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
client = TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash)
client.start()
```

And on command prompt:

```
pip3 install telethon

python3 C:/TG/First.py
```

Result:

> Please enter your phone (or bot token)

If I give my API ID, it eventually throws the error:

> telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.PhoneNumberInvalidError: The phone number is invalid (caused by SendCodeRequest)

Why? I expect the client to start without errors.

PS: my API ID is 7 digits long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message suggests, your phone number is invalid. Maybe you didn't enter it in international format?

Comment: I am so stupid. I was entering API ID instead of phone number when it clearly says enter phone. I thought API ID is something like a phone number but for the software. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

This will only occure at your first use just enter your Phone Number starting with + then you will recive a code which you have to enter next. This is just to Authorise your Laptop beeing loged in to Telegram.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are giving your **API ID**, but it is asking for your phone number in international format like `+91xxxxxxxxxx`